# PHP with PDO fetch_assoc Array sorting/grouping by certain value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, pdo, grouping

I have a var_dumped Array from PDO Fetch_assoc like:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'Client_Firstname' => string 'Sandrah' (length=...)
      'Client_Lastname' => string 'Lewis' (length=...)
      'Client_Email' => string 'san@lewis.com' (length=...)
      'Purchased_ItemId' => int '16' (length=...)
      'ItemName' => string 'MiniPad' (length=...)
      'ItemPrice' => string '500.00' (length=...)
      'ItemType' => string 'Hardware' (length=...)
      'date' => string '2013-12-12' (length=...)
  1 => 
     array
      'Client_Firstname' => string 'Derick' (length=...)
      'Client_Lastname' => string 'Smith' (length=...)
      'Client_Email' => string 'der@smith.com' (length=...)
      'Purchased_ItemId' => int '10' (length=...)
      'ItemName' => string 'MegaPad' (length=...)
      'ItemPrice' => string '1500.00' (length=...)
      'ItemType' => string 'Hardware' (length=...)
      'date' => string '2013-12-12' (length=...)
  2 => 
     array
      'Client_Firstname' => string 'Sandrah' (length=...)
      'Client_Lastname' => string 'Lewis' (length=...)
      'Client_Email' => string 'san@lewis.com' (length=...)
      'Purchased_ItemId' => int '18' (length=...)
      'ItemName' => string 'Xpower Speakers' (length=...)
      'ItemPrice' => string '300.00' (length=...)
      'ItemType' => string 'Hardware' (length=...)
      'date' => string '2013-12-12' (length=...)
  3 => 
     array
      'Client_Firstname' => string 'Sandrah' (length=1)
      'Client_Lastname' => string 'Lewis' (length=7)
      'Client_Email' => string 'san@lewis.com' (length=7)
      'Purchased_ItemId' => int '7' (length=7)
      'ItemName' => string 'Lion Belt' (length=7)
      'ItemPrice' => string '800.00' (length=7)
      'ItemType' => string 'Fashion' (length=7)
      'date' => string '2013-12-12' (length=7)
  4 => 
    array
      'Client_Firstname' => string 'Sandrah' (length=1)
      'Client_Lastname' => string 'Lewis' (length=7)
      'Client_Email' => string 'san@lewis.com' (length=7)
      'Purchased_ItemId' => int '27' (length=7)
      'ItemName' => string 'FT Card Reader' (length=7)
      'ItemPrice' => string '20.00' (length=7)
      'ItemType' => string 'Hardware' (length=7)
      'date' => string '2013-12-12' (length=7)
  5 => 
     array
      'Client_Firstname' => string 'Jonathan' (length=1)
      'Client_Lastname' => string 'Homad' (length=7)
      'Client_Email' => string 'jon@homad.com' (length=7)
      'Purchased_ItemId' => int '20' (length=7)
      'ItemName' => string 'MiniPad' (length=7)
      'ItemPrice' => string '500.00' (length=7)
      'ItemType' => string 'Hardware' (length=7)
      'date' => string '2013-12-12' (length=7)
```

The aim is that, in the out put, each client's Firstname, Lastname and Email should appear only once followed by all h/er transaction.

Something like:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'Client_Firstname' => string 'Sandrah' (length=...)
      'Client_Lastname' => string 'Lewis' (length=...)
      'Client_Email' => string 'san@lewis.com' (length=...)
      'Purchased_ItemId' => int '16' (length=...)
      'ItemName' => string 'MiniPad' (length=...)
      'ItemPrice' => string '500.00' (length=...)
      'ItemType' => string 'Hardware' (length=...)
      'date' => string '2013-12-12' (length=...)
      'Purchased_ItemId' => int '18' (length=...)
      'ItemName' => string 'Xpower Speakers' (length=...)
      'ItemPrice' => string '300.00' (length=...)
      'ItemType' => string 'Hardware' (length=...)
      'date' => string '2013-12-12' (length=...)
      'Purchased_ItemId' => int '7' (length=...)
      'ItemName' => string 'Lion Belt' (length=...)
      'ItemPrice' => string '800.00' (length=...)
      'ItemType' => string 'Fashion' (length=...)
      'date' => string '2013-12-12' (length=...)
      'Purchased_ItemId' => int '27' (length=...)
      'ItemName' => string 'FT Card Reader' (length=...)
      'ItemPrice' => string '20.00' (length=...)
      'ItemType' => string 'Hardware' (length=...)
      'date' => string '2013-12-12' (length=...)

  1 => 

     array
      'Client_Firstname' => string 'Derick' (length=...)
      'Client_Lastname' => string 'Smith' (length=...)
      'Client_Email' => string 'der@smith.com' (length=...)
      'Purchased_ItemId' => int '10' (length=...)
      'ItemName' => string 'MegaPad' (length=...)
      'ItemPrice' => string '1500.00' (length=...)
      'ItemType' => string 'Hardware' (length=...)
      'date' => string '2013-12-12' (length=...)

  2 => 

     array
      'Client_Firstname' => string 'Jonathan' (length=...)
      'Client_Lastname' => string 'Homad' (length=...)
      'Client_Email' => string 'jon@homad.com' (length=...)
      'Purchased_ItemId' => int '20' (length=...)
      'ItemName' => string 'MiniPad' (length=...)
      'ItemPrice' => string '500.00' (length=...)
      'ItemType' => string 'Hardware' (length=...)
      'date' => string '2013-12-12' (length=...)
```

The only unique identifier in each array according to me is the Email address. So, I tried using for loop, foreach loop trying to group them according to the Email addresses, guided by other SO related questions but this is not yet achieved.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: You probably want to add an ORDER BY Client_Email in your query

Comment: I have narrowed it down to a basic query like: `"SELECT * FROM dailyDeals_tb "`. With this, when `var_dump`ed, it looks like that and somehow there is a feeling that the output result can be easily achieved using PHP...but HOW?